# HTTP_ACCESS returned when invoking file_get_contents (and also simple_html_dom)

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the contents of a page this way:

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; 
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                    'method'  => 'GET',
                    'timeout' => 10
            )
    );
    $domain = "http://www.esperandoaramon.com";
    //$domain = "http://www.google.com";
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $input = @file_get_contents($domain,false,$context) or die("Could not access file:    $domain");
    echo($input);
?>
```

I can get www.google.com contents this way, unfortunately the other domain gives me only this notification:

```
Notice:
Text: Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT
File: /home/trdeport/public_html/esperandoaramon/_visit.php
Line: 4
```

This HTTP_ACCEPT is killing me... the page runs perfectly on a browser. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with the site at the other end, not with your script. I suspect that the other site expects an `Accept` header and when it doesn't have one, it fails (it works with your browser because the browser always sends that header.) Try setting it in your stream context options:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 10,
        'header' => "Accept: text/html\r\n"
    )
);
```

Comment: I finally had to add following your explanation this: 'header' => "Accept: text/html\r\n" . "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"